# What embedded browser for C++ project?

Tags: c++, browser

Is there any browser I could embedd in C++ application on Windows?

I need all features typical browser has (HTTP client, cookies support, DOM style HTML parser, JavaScript engine) **except** rendering.
Because I don't need rendering capability (and that's rather big part of a browser) I would prefer a browser with non monolithic design so I wouldn't have to include rendering stuff into my project.

It would be nice if it had C++ rather than C API.

I need this embedded browser mainly because I have much trouble finding C++ HTML parser which could handle broken HTML like browsers do.
If you know any, please answer [Library Recommendation: C++ HTML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser) SO question or at least vote on it to increase a chance someone will give a good answer.

Comment: You really should specify which platform this is for.  Something that may be a good choice on Windows isn't necessarily going to be available on OS X for example.

Comment: It's for Windows. I added this info to the question. Thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question regarding embedding a web browser for which you don't need rendering capabilities. A web browser is rendering web pages by definition, unless you just need HTTP and XML with JavaScript capabilities which is a subset of a browser functionalities?

If you need a web browser to embed in your C++ application, I would suggest to consider Qt that comes with the WebKit plugin. It is C++, LGPL and has a very nice IDE (Qt Creator). I tried Qt with Qt Creator on unix (Ubuntu) and it was very impressive. The debugger is a bit light but it is just the first version. The adapter of Qt into visual c++ 2008 is now free.

Comment: Yep, I need HTTP, cookies, HTML (not XML!) parser and JavaScript. I added all these to the question to make it even more clear :)

Comment: I would then suggest to use webkit because it is quite efficient, especially the JavaScript interpretor. Just use the functionalities you are interested in.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like all you need is something like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) which is an HTTP library and will let you do GET/POST/etc.

When I think browser I generally think rendering/JavaScript and not HTTP library.

**Edit**

In that case I'd look at [WebKit](http://webkit.org/) (which I think has a C++ API) and hope you don't have to pull too much in.

**Edit Again**

On second thought (since rendering is such a big part of what browsers do), you might be better off using a stand-alone JS engine like [SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/) and a stand-alone XML parser like [Xerces-C](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) (plus maybe [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to make your HTML into XML).

Comment: I'm already using it. I need JavaScript engine and html parser and libcurl doesn't have these things.

Comment: It would have been sensible to list those requirements in the question.

Comment: @Neil: It was easier to say what I don't need since that's only one thing and all other features I need :)

Comment: @Piotr ... yes and no. It's kind of obvious that we were confused about what you want ;)

Comment: @Aaron: I was looking at Tidy but the first thing I check when I look for a library is how active the project is. The last entry in News section of Tidy project is one year old... I was also amazed there isn't any component based on Xerces-C which would handle HTML. There is such - called NekoHTML - but it's only for Xerces-Java. It's very sad there's no good, stand-alone HTML parser for such a popular language as C++...

Answer (score 6):

You might also want to check out [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com)-- it's free for non-commercial use and has all of the features you're looking for (if you don't need rendering, simply don't use it).

Comment: Old question I know, but I was looking for the exact same thing as the OP. You answer helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There is a project called CEF = [The Chromium Embedded Framework](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) - it is:

> a simple framework for
>   embedding Chromium-based browsers in other applications. It is a
>   BSD-licensed open source project founded by Marshall Greenblatt in
>   2008 and based on the Google Chromium project. Unlike the Chromium
>   project itself, which focuses mainly on Google Chrome application
>   development, CEF focuses on facilitating embedded browser use cases in
>   third-party applications.

and yes:

> The base CEF framework includes support for the C and C++ programming
>   languages.

Answer (score 3):

Including javascript support and html parsing makes this non-trivial task - you have to use one of the available browsers.

- IE is usable through its COM model - you can create instance of it in your window be it invisible or not and call its javascript/html capabilities.

It has been designed to be used like that since the beginning and certainly it is working fine.

The other options are:

- Gecko/Mozilla - a couple of years ago it wasn't usable like this, currently I think it is.
- WebKit/V8 - no public API has been released for chrome yet, you could use webkit itself, but it doesn't have javascript engine. Another option is to take a look at the Chrome codebase and see if you could get out of it what you need.

I would probably go for IE, since it is maybe the easiest option and I have already used it. The other options seem to me more like building a browser instead of just using it.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko) ? You may not need the entire engine but you may find some its components useful like [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey) which is a JavaScript engine written in C.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend picking up Qt for C++ programming. It has a built-in library that [embeds Webkit](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/webkit-previewer.html) with all the bells'n'whistles, and Qt is a great C++ library in general.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but take a look on 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky29ffxd%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

IActiveScript and family COM interfaces allows script execution (not only JS, any language that registers as script interpeter, for that matter) in-memory.