# I want to make a web browser, but I'm not sure where to start?

Tags: java, browser, cross-platform, webkit

I want to use [WebKit](http://webkit.org/) as the layout/rendering engine, and I want to code it in Java. I am having troubles finding any useful info. I saw this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598841/how-to-get-started-building-a-web-browser) which cleared things for me slightly, but I need more to get started.

I would like to know:

1. If I can use Java?
2. Where can I find documentation on how to work with and use WebKit? ( I am looking for something like the [Java API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/) )
3. Is there a WebKit build compiled for Linux? ( Specifically Ubuntu/Debian )

My plan thus far:

1. Learn to use/interact with WebKit and its components specifically JavascriptCore.
2. Create the UI, etc. in Java and create a basic browser. ( For now, I want to create a basic window that can display a webpage correctly. )

Sorry if this isn't very clear. I am still hatching ideas, and I am not really sure what I want to find or need in order to move forward.

Edit: I just came across this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184373/what-is-the-best-html-rendering-engine-to-embed-in-an-application).  I want to do something like that; so I guess what I am wondering is how do I go about embedding an engine like this into an application that I make myself?  I also forgot to mention that I am willing to do this in other languages. ( By this I mean C++ )

Comment: psst.  We don't need another browser.  ;)

Comment: @Paul Prewett: I know there are tons of browsers but I am bored and I like to learn almost anything programming/computer related.  Times are tough and I am almost out of college and I need to try to get a leg up on people, lol.  Knowledge is power, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Yes, it's possible. A [google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=webkit+java+browser&aq=0&oq=webkit+java+b&aqi=g1) for "WebKit Java Browser" brings up several projects.

2: The best I could find in terms of documentation is the documentation section in the [WebKit wiki](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki).

3: Here's a [guide](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingQtOnLinux) to making a WebKit build on Linux using QT.

Answer (score 1):

Hope for [JWebPane](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ixmal/archive/2008/05/introducing_jwe.html) to be released and go from there

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://www.concord.org/~dmarkman/jws/webkit/  Alternatively if you are comfortable with Qt has a webbrowser control as well.  Its quite easy with Qt, you just drag and drop the webbrowser control on the UI.

You can check out several examples of webkit control for Qt at (URl ommitted due to first time answer), just do a search for webkit Qt on google theres lots of examples on the Qt Website. cheers

Comment: I was just starting to look at Qt.  But I am not sure if I use something that does so much for me. ( Specifically the drag and drop webcontrol ) I like trying to figure this kind of stuff out for myself.  Thanks for the information though.